# conversion of namespace to nodename in lxml - python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am using lxml library... I have a tag in an `xml` file called

`<a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>` 
and the prefix `a` refers to namespace

```
a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"^
```

When I use lxml-Xpath to get the tag name as `a:rPr` I get the result as `{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main}rPr'`

Here is the code snippet I have written:

```
if doc == 'file.xml':
        file = etree.parse(my_directory+doc)
        path = file.xpath('/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:rPr', namespaces={'p':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main',
            'a':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'})
        #print path
        for a in path:
            print a.tag
```

I have used xml.minidom where I can use `a.nodeName` to get the tagname but I do not have any idea which function could give me the tag name without namespace i.e `a:rPr` in lxml?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath's `name()`:

```
for a in path:
    print a.xpath('name()')  # prints a:rPr
```

Hope that helps.